# Search query when the search sentence is less than characters

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, search, orm

How can such a search be implemented in Django ORM(or SQL query)
There is an arbitrary table with the field name "description".
There is one entry, and the value of the field "description" is python.
How to formulate a database search query to get this record if the incoming sentence looks like this: python-is a great programming-language.
Thank you.

Requests of the form
`

```
Entry.objects.get(headline__icontains="Lennon")
```

are not suitable because there are fewer characters in the searched sentence

Comment: check it helps, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

Comment: Doing something like this in SQL seems like a very bad idea as SQL simply wasn't designed to handle searches like this. https://django-opensearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ is probably a better direction to go.

Comment: There may be an elegant solution. But as it stands, the question is barely defined. Please clarify the objective. How do you want to match *exactly*? And tell us your version of Postgres.

Comment: There is 1 entry in the table.
The value of the "description" field is  - "python"
The string on which the search is being made, in the "description" field - "python is an excellent programming language."
How to get this entry?
Version Postgresql - 13.1
Thank you.